# Understanding generic interface inheritance and assigmnet

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, covariance

If I have this example interface:

```
public class BaseReq { }
public class BaseResp { }

public interface IService<in TReq, out TResp>
    where TReq : BaseReq
    where TResp : BaseResp
{
    // Methods
    // ...
}
```

And I have two "types" of this service that I implement as derived interfaces:

```
public class TypeAReq : BaseReq { }
public class TypeAResp : BaseResp { }
public interface IServiceTypeA : IService<TypeAReq, TypeAResp> { }

public class TypeBReq : BaseReq { }
public class TypeBResp : BaseResp { }
public interface IServiceTypeB : IService<TypeBReq, TypeBResp> { }
```

Lastly, if I attempt to assign to a variable that *should* be assignable to both interfaces:

```
IServiceTypeA GetTypeAService() { ... }
IServiceTypeB GetTypeBService() { ... }

void Run()
{
    IService<BaseReq, BaseResp> myService = someFlag
        ? GetTypeAService()
        : GetTypeBService();
}
```

I get an error saying:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `IService<TypeAReq, TypeAResp>` to `IService<BaseReq, BaseResp>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

And if I attempt to cast it, ReSharper warns me by saying:

> Suspicious cast: there is no type that inherits from both `IService<TypeAReq, TypeAResp>` and `IService<BaseReq, BaseResp>`.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Shouldn't the types be castable because they inherit from the base classes?

Comment: `IService` is contravariant in `TReq` so you need `BaseReq` to be a subtype not a base type of `TypeAReq` for the conversion to be valid.

Comment: @Lee I'm a bit confused by your comment. What is the different between a subtype and a base type? Or can you explain what change I need to make in order for this to work?

Comment: If `A` is a base type of `B` then `B` is a subtype of `A`. In this case `TypeAReq` and `TypeBReq` are both subtypes of `BaseReq`. Your assignment to `myService` is not allowed because it could be unsafe since it would allow you to pass a request type to `myService` it cannot handle e.g. `IService<BaseReq, BaseResp> myService = GetTypeAService(); myService.Handle(new TypeBReq());`. There's no static way to make this work so you either need to redesign, cast, or do some runtime checking (e.g. reflection) to handle the invocation.